# Redirect If Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a domain called "wlatw.co" (and .com) ('**Wow! Look At This Website!**') that let's me and some of my friends make shortened URLS. I've just upgraded it from a slow version that dealt with some gross javascript to a super fast PHP header() redirect. It used to be like this: "r.wlatw.co/alca", but I would prefer "wlatw.co/alca". I want .htaccess to redirect missing pages, like "/alca" (since it doesn't exist on the server), to "wlatw.co/redir.php?r=alca" where it will redirect from.
(Put a comma and a period outside of the quotes as to not confuse someone :) )

wlatw.co/*RedirectName* = 404 **redirect** redir.php?r=*RedirectName* **redirect** *Page To Redirect To*

*a* **redirect** *b* **redirect** c

a to b by .htaccess. From b to c by redir.php.

So unless someone knows some type of way to read an XML with htaccess, I'd prefer this method!

---

### XML Setup Example:

.. if it need it (Or for reference by someone passing through)

```
<redirect>
    <short>
        <name>alca</name>                     <!-- like wlatw.co/alca -->
        <creator>255.255.255.255</creator>    <!-- ip address or username -->
        <date>1/6/13</date>                   <!-- the date! -->
        <time>10:52PM</time>                  <!-- the time! -->
        <url>http://www.alcadesign.com/</url> <!-- where to go to -->
    </short>
</redirect>
```

And the

### PHP:

This is the **redir.php**

```
<?php
    if(file_exists('redirects.xml')) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('redirects.xml');
        if(isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] != '' && !is_array($_GET['r'])) {
            foreach($xml->short as $shorts) {
                if($shorts->name == $_GET['r']) {
                    header('Location: '.$shorts->url);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            header("refresh:2;url=http://www.wlatw.co/");
            echo '<div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px;">Malformed URL</div><div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Redirecting...</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Pertaining to the PHP, if anyone knows how to tell from the foreach loop if it was successful or not and echo

Comment: you should add a `break` to break out of the loop after a valid match is found. Also you should check to see that `$_GET['r']` is not an array (e.g. `$_GET['r'] AND !is_array($_GET['r']);`

Comment: What is your question? Seems like you're just explaining what you're doing.

Comment: The question is "How to use .htaccess to redirect if the file is not found, like "/alca" (does not exist of the server) to "/redir.php?r=alca"?

Comment: Is /alca an actual file, or does it only exist as an entry in the xml?

Comment: It's only an entry in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't quite work the way you're expecting it to.

`.htaccess` is part of Apache, which is done doing it's thing by the time your PHP executes. There's no way to go back to go back to the `.htaccess` short of reloading the page.

If you're already in a PHP file, and already have what you want in `$_GET['r']`, then simply `include('redir.php');` after you determine that the entry doesn't exist in your XML.

Comment: No, sorry, let me clarify. You go to wlatw.co/alca and get redirected by .htaccess, because the page does not exist, to wlatw.co/redir.php?r=alca where that PHP code exists to be redirected. (clarifying the post to reflect)

Answer (score 0):

No one appears to be responding with a proper answer, so I looked around more and found this cheat-sheet:
http://www.addedbytes.com/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/

I modified the "Nice looking URLs" example for my usage:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ redir.php?r=$1 [L]
```